# Elementary question about hypothesis for the Poisson Summation Formula

Tags: fourier-transform, poisson-summation-formula

**Updated:** Clarified the question.

I'm stuck in what must be a basic misunderstanding of the necessary hypotheses for the Poisson Summation Formula.

Suppose $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$, then we have

$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi i x w} \, dx = e^{-2\pi^2 \omega^2}.$$

The source I'm using states the Poisson Summation Formula as follows:

> Suppose $L > 0$ Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Further suppose that
>   $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}\left(\frac{k}{L}\right) < +\infty,$$
>   then
>    $$
>     \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty f(kL) = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}\left( \frac{k}{L} \right ).$$

It seems to me that this can't be correct as stated, since for any $f$ satisfying the hypothesis, we can change the function on a set of measure zero and still satisfy the hypothesis, but change the left hand side of the formula without changing the right.

For example, if $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$, then we have

$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi i x w} \, dx = e^{-2\pi^2 \omega^2}.$$

If we let 
 $$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = kL, k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ f(x) & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

Then, since $g = f$ a.e., we have $\hat{g} = \hat{f}$. But this would imply
$$\sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty f(kL) = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}\left( \frac{k}{L} \right ) = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{g}\left( \frac{k}{L} \right ) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty g(kL) = 0$$
which is wrong.

> What's wrong with these hypothesis? Can anyone provide a bit of guidance on what's the correct way to think about necessary conditions for the PSF?

Comment: The Poisson summation formula has _hypotheses_, which are not satisfied in that example. (What hypotheses? There are many different versions. Go back to wherever you learned about Poisson summation and re-read the fine print...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I agree that's the issue. I've updated my question - I'm hoping for some intuitive guidance on what some natural necessary conditions for the PSF are.

Comment: Have you tried simply looking to see what the hypotheses are in whatever source you learned about PSF from? If you look it up on Wikipedia you find a lot of stuff about "for suitable functions", and then finally there's a statement of a set of sufficient hypotheses: $f$ should be a continuous integrable function such that $|f(t)|+|\hat f(t)|\le c(1+|t|)^{-\alpha}$ for some $\alpha>1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Before your most recent comment I updated clarifying the question and including the hypotheses of the source I'm using. I'm familiar with the statement on Wikipedia, S&S, etc - my question isn't about finding any necessary conditions for the PSF to hold, but what a good way to think about what is necessary. For instance, when (if ever?) does the PSF hold for discontinuous functions?

Comment: You're right, _that_ statement is not correct as stated. They assume that $\hat f\in L^1$. This means that $f$ is the inverse transform of $\hat f$ almost everywhere, and that that inverse transform is continuous. What they're tacitly assuming is that $f$ has been defined to be that inverse transform everywhere. Which given that $\hat f\in L^1$ is the same as assuming that $f$ is continuous. It's somewhere between an error or a convention: people say that if $\hat f\in L^1$ then $f$ is continuous...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's very helpful! Thank you.